# replace files from a source to destination

Tags: c#, file, replace

I Need to replace multiple files from a source folder to a destination folder and thats the code i've written.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace bestem_re
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            string[] fnames;
            string[] dfnames;
            string destination;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

// In this I am fetching the source of the destination files.            

//using the for each loop to iterate to all the selected files
private void btnsource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();



                opf.Multiselect = true;
                if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    fnames = opf.FileNames;
                    foreach (var item in fnames)
                    {

                        txtsource.Text = txtsource.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item) + "  ";
                    }

                }


            }
// I Am fetching the destination of the files that are to be replaced.      
            private void btndestination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog opf1 = new OpenFileDialog();



                opf1.Multiselect = true;
                if (opf1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    dfnames = opf1.FileNames;
                    foreach (var item in dfnames)
                    {

                        txtdestination.Text = txtdestination.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item) + "  ";
                    }
                }

            }
//this is the replace function where in I carry out the process of replacing the files    
            private void btnreplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string source;
                int i = 0;

                destination = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dfnames[0]);
                MessageBox.Show(destination);


                foreach (var item in fnames)
                {
                    source = item;
                    string fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fnames[i]);
                    string dfname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dfnames[i]);
                    string FileToBackUp = destination + @"\" + dfname + ".bac";
                    MessageBox.Show("Bestem BOX");
                    System.IO.File.Replace(source, destination, FileToBackUp);
                    System.IO.File.Copy(destination, source);
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfull");
                    destination = "";
                    i++;
                }

            }

        }
    }

//replace files from source to destination
```

Comment: You should take more time to describe your problem, wanted behavior (input, output, side effects) and actual behavior (what is currently happening that you don't want?)

Comment: If I try to replace a single file it works fine, but if i use the foreach loop and try to replace multiple files it throws the error saying there are no permissions

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just your `System.IO.File.Copy(destination, source)` comming back to haunt you? No Idea why you try to copy back from destination to source after the replace, but this `Copy` overload is promising you an [`IOException` if destFileName exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx#Exceptions). I think I got it... gonna write some answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague. In the code above I must question using an `OpenFileDialog` to get the files and then again to set a destination. This not only looks odd but is open for files getting saved to the incorrect locations and file name.

When you allow the user to select x number of files with the open file dialog then ask the user to select the destination files for a backup using a different open file dialog has some serious problems? If this is the case as it appears so, the user would have to pick the SAME exact files in the same order for this to work properly. Having the user select the destinations seems odd and error prone.

Simply use the files the user selected in the first open file dialog then backup those files to a set destination folder, in this case the same folder with a “.bac” extension added at the end of the file name. The code below does this using an open file dialog to get the files to backup. `btnsource_Click` calls `BackupFiles` so only one button is pressed to back up the selected files.  I hope this makes sense.

```
private void btnsource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  OpenFileDialog opf = new OpenFileDialog();
  opf.Multiselect = true;
  if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    string[] fnames = opf.FileNames;
    foreach (var item in fnames) {
      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item) + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    BackupFiles(fnames);
  }
}

private void BackupFiles(string[] fnames) {
  string source;
  int i = 0;
  string destination = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fnames[0]);
  string fname = "";
  string FileToBackUp = "";

  foreach (var item in fnames) {
    source = item;
    fname = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fnames[i]);
    FileToBackUp = destination + @"\" + fname + ".bac";
    File.Copy(source, FileToBackUp, true);
    i++;
  }
  MessageBox.Show("Successfull");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `destination`:

```
destination = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dfnames[0]); // is a directory
// usage:
System.IO.File.Replace(source, destination, FileToBackUp);
```

Will throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` because

> [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9h163f(v=vs.110).aspx#Exceptions)
>
> [... if] Source or destination parameters specify a directory instead of a
>   file.